# cypress check color of css background

Tags: cypress

I have this assertion :

```
cy.get('.myelement').should('have.css', 'background-color','rgb(75, 221, 51)')
```

I want to replace it with hexadecimal representation as following:

```
cy.get('.myelement').should('have.css', 'background-color','#4BDD33')
```

but I get this error from cypress :

expected <.myelement> to have CSS property background-color with the value #4BDD33, but the value was rgb(75, 221, 51)
any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. Install the [rgb-hex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rgb-hex) package

```js
npm install rgb-hex
```

2. In your test suite file import the package

```js
import rgbHex from 'rgb-hex';
```

3. In your test write:

```js
cy.get('.myelement')
  .invoke('css', 'background-color')
  .then((bgcolor) => {
    expect(rgbHex(bgcolor)).to.eq('4bdd33')
  })
```

Comment: just for some reason I have to remove the hashtag # and also write the code in small letters .
so it will be eq('4bdd33')
any idea why that?

Comment: @Deyaa If you look into the plugin page https://www.npmjs.com/package/rgb-hex, the hex value is returned without the `#`

Answer (score 5):

I'd take the reverse approach of Alapan -- I prefer to modify my *expected* and leave my actual values alone. To do this, you'd need a way to turn your expected Hex value into the rgb() format.

```js
const hexToRgb = (hex) => {
  const rValue = ParseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16);
  const gValue = ParseInt(hex.substring(2, 4), 16);
  const bValue = ParseInt(hex.substring(4), 16);
  return `rgb(${rValue}, ${gValue}, ${bValue})`;
}

cy.get('.myelement').should('have.css', 'background-color', hexToRgb('4BDD33'));
```

If you wanted to include the `#` in the hex string, you would just need to ignore it in setting the values, most likely by increasing every number in the `substring()` functions by one.

Overall, I think that Alapan's solution is easier, but this is just something to consider.